# ListView layout issue flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and have made an app using ListView. I had a problem when trying to align leading, title and trailing to the top (red line) so I set the parameter isThreeLine to true which solved the issue. But that added extra space below the subtitle (blue arrow) that I can't seem to get rid off. I also tried setting the titleAlignment parameter to its various values but the result is not the same as the red line alignment shown in picture. Here's the problem:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final cStudent = students[index];
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.asset(
        cStudent.profileImage,
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
      ),
      isThreeLine: true,
      title: Text(cStudent.fullName),
      subtitle: Text('Roll No: ${cStudent.rollNo.toString()}'),
      trailing: Text('Std: ${cStudent.standard.toString()}'),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => kDivider,
  itemCount: students.length,
)
```

I am running the code on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Remove**

```
isThreeLine: true,
```

**Use Like This**

```
ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      // final cStudent = students[index];
      return ListTile(
        leading: Container(
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
        ),
        title: const Text("Full name"),
        subtitle: const Text('Roll No: '),
        trailing: const Text('Std: '),
      );
    },
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
    itemCount: 10,
  ),
```